# Is possible to download all the images from a website based on a increasing/incrementing number link? (e.g. 0001.png, 0002.png, etc.)

Tags: download, website, links, tree

It's possible to download every image based on this link adress:

http://d1ilncjhg2cjw.cloudfront.net/hub/assets/FULL_DROP_JAN_2015/large/SONY_FULL_DROP_05_00900.jpg

http://d1ilncjhg2cjw.cloudfront.net/hub/assets/FULL_DROP_JAN_2015/large/SONY_FULL_DROP_05_01010.jpg

As you can see, it ends in 00901.jpg / 00902.jpg / 00903.jpg / etc.

Is it possible to download all the images from 00000 to 01473? (that's the last image)

Comment: Yes it is possible through scripting or programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use "curl" to easily do this. Here is the website to download:

- Help Page: https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html
- Download page: https://curl.haxx.se/download.html (Just scroll down to the correct package, such as Windows binary if you're on Windows)

All you have to do is pass the correct sequence to the curl executable and you're good.

Here is the exact line of code you can use with curl in your case. Make sure to run from the command window in the same folder as the "curl.exe" is in:

```
curl http://d1ilncjhg2cjw.cloudfront.net/hub/assets/FULL_DROP_JAN_2015/large/SONY_FULL_DROP_05_[00000-10000].jpg -o ".\download\pic#1.jpg"
```

- Where the "00000-10000" in brackets represents the numbers you want to scan. This should do the trick. It might take a while though.
- Where "#1" represents the same numbers in the file output. You can change the output directory, in my example it will output in a sub-directory called "download"

Update: I tested my command and it works fine with your site. So this should do what you want it to.

Alternatives: 
If you don't want to use curl, there are alternatives like:

- wget for Windows: http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm
- Powershell "Invoke-WebRequest"
- Powershell "Net.WebClient"

But I won't get into details on how to accomplish this with those tools.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use curl, I've tried to download all the windows versions and as soon as I open the curl exe, it shows a cmd window and disappears instantly. **Any idea?**

Comment: @m30l Open a `cmd` window first and then run `curl`

Comment: @m30l Just open a command window first in the folder that has curl in it. (Shift + right-click in the folder then select "open command window here"). Then in that command window, type the command in my answer above.

Comment: Thank you. In case someone is wondering how to download "0.mp4, 1.mp4, 2.mp4, 3.mp4, ..., 700.mp4", replace the [00000-10000] with [0-700].